# Any good new ways in C++11 to store, as members, "cloned" objects of other "hierarchy-classes"?

Tags: c++

We have a `Base` class and a `Derived` class that derives from `Base`.

In some other class, we want to have a member of type `shared_ptr<Base>`.

We cannot use the type `Base` directly because direct copying like that will rule out subclasses.

However, we still want to "copy" the `Base` (or subclass) object over upon construction, because we want to rule out the possibility of it being modified.

The classic way to deal with this is to put a virtual member function `clone()` into the `Base` class that every subclass of `Base` can then implement. Every `clone()` would then just return a "copy" of itself - for example, `Derived` would return `make_shared<Derived>(*this)`.

The problem with this approach is that this requires every new subclass of `Base` to implement this `clone()` function. The code in each `clone()` is rather boilerplate, and it seems somewhat unnatural to be repeating it all the time.

Any better ways to do this since C++11?

Comment: I have a feeling that the answer is no as the old problem of trying to determine the run-time type at compile time still remains and none of the new features have anything to offer in that regard or this type of boilerplate code generation.  I would like to be proven wrong through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has always been possible to do this in plain C++:

```
struct base
{
    virtual ~base () {}
    virtual base* clone () = 0;  
    virtual void foo () = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct base_impl : base
{
    T* clone () { return new T (*static_cast<T*> (this)); }
};

struct derived : base_impl<derived>
{ 
    void foo () { ... }
};

struct derived2 : base_impl<derived2>
{
    void foo () { ...}
};
```

etc.

You can improve this with C++11: you can use `unique_ptr<base>` (but you lose the covariant return type), you can make the destructor of `base_impl` private and use `friend T`.

I agree that this is not very flexible in this case but:

- many layered hierarchies are not very common
- clone functions are not very useful
- the design is nevertheless extensible and goes beyond cloning: using templates as a way to automate boilerplate code is used thoroughly in eg. ATL and WTL. Search for "curiously recurring template pattern".

Another solution. This can probably be improved in various ways, but I think you can't avoid having two clone functions:

```
struct base
{
    std::unique_ptr<base> clone () { return std::unique_ptr<base> (do_clone ()); }

private:
    virtual base *do_clone () = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct base_impl : base
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> clone () 
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<T> (static_cast<T*> (do_clone ()));
    }    

private:
    base *do_clone () { return new T (*static_cast<T*> (this)); }
};
```

Comment: I'm surprised that works.  I can kind of get my head around it, but it's definitely counter-intuitive to inherit from a class that has a template argument of the derived class itself.

Comment: Any chance you can also outline the `unique_ptr` solution in more detail? (I take it that you think `shared_ptr` is bad for this?)

Comment: @DennisRitchie: When writing factory functions, always return `unique_ptr`, because they are convertible to `shared_ptr`. I can outline a solution (but it is quite ugly).